# LED strip power injection

Tags: power-supply, led-strip

I want to power inject my 6m LED strip after every 2 meters. I wondered if it makes any difference on how I set it up.

Do I need to connect the ground from the power supply like in the top figure? Or can I use the ground provided from the previous led? [image]

Comment: I think it's better to connect the ground to the power supply *and* to the previous strip

Answer (score 1):

Since the ground line needs to carry 100% of the current, your second approach makes little sense: you're effectively shifting the ground level of the "right-hand" sub-strips up, thus reducing the available supply voltage, still.

But: also your first scheme isn't great. Connect both positive supply and ground at *both* ends of your strips, not just at one end, to minimize ground shift at the end of each strip – otherwise, the "blue" data signal connection is referenced to a different notion of ground on the transmitting and the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to inject the power every to meters to reduce voltage drop over the resistance of the LED strip boards.
I would also assume that the ground and the power path through the PCB have a similar resistance.

With these assumptions it makes little sense to only wire power to the boards externally, because all of the current still has to pass through the return path of all boards and by that still creates larger losses.
If you start with the hassle of external wiring I would do it completely and also wire ground externally as well.

Answer (score 0):

It does make a difference how you set it up. 
First you need to make sure that whatever is sending data has its own ground or 0V level connected to the beginning of the strip AND that you have a separate ground (0V) wire going from that point (where the data-sending device and the beginning of the strip connect together) to the the ground of the power supply which also supplies or has short ground lead towards the data-sending device's supply. 
This is needed to ensure that the ground for both the beginning of the strip and the data-sending device is at 0V for proper communication. 
The rest of the strip shouldn't have as much problem with a shifting ground because each LED chip forwards/buffers its own data signal which is referenced to its own ground, so even if the ground shifts significantly between one end of the strip and the other, the communication would still be fine.

If you're adding another supply line in parallel like you're suggesting, typically you should start with the ground line to reduce the voltage drops there. 
If you are supplying only one side with the external wire, you will have double the voltage drop as compared to supplying both sides (positive and negative or ground/0V and +5V), so do both if you're already doing that.